# JQuery Slide Down positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

I've having a problem using the JQuery slide down function. I can get it to work fine however the position of the element I'm sliding down changes depending on the size of the viewport.  What I would like to do is sort of tie it to the element it's sliding from.

[***This JSfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/129/) sort of illustrates the problem I'm having. I would like the `.drop` element to line up with the right edge of the `.opener` element.

*CSS*

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.box .opener {
    display: block;
    background: #faa;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.box .drop {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #afa;
    bottom: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.opener').click(function(e){
    $('.drop').slideDown();
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: +1 Why downvote? I understand this clearly, although the text formatting is quite bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you use `float: left; margin-left: 500px; position: absolute;`. You don't know CSS properties? Use `right:0;` and remove `float: left; margin-left: 500px;`. Like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct9P4/)

Comment: Aye my CSS skills aren't the best. Your answer works perfectly though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve, I just had to remove some of the positioning.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/143/

CSS:

```
.box .opener {
    display: block;
    background: #faa;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.box .drop {
    display: none;
    background: #afa;
}
```

Comment: I should have probably made it clear that I need the .drop element to be a particular size and it actually has to slide up. I used Slide down because as far as I'm aware there is no slide up function in JQuery.